# storing query outputs dynamically TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a loop over different tables which returns results
with different number of columns.

Is it possible to store the output of a query without creating a concrete table?

I've read some posts regarding temporary tables so I tried this simple example:

```
create table #temp_table1 (id int)

insert into #temp_table1 ('select * from table1')
```

table1 above could be any table

I get the following error message:

Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Is there anyway to avoid having hard code table definitions exactly matching the output of your query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a `select into` - that will create the temporary table automatically:

```
SELECT * INTO #Temp
FROM TableName
```

The problem is that since you are using dynamic SQL , your temporary table will only be available inside the dynamic SQL scope - so doing something like this will result with an error:

```
EXEC('SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM TableName')

SELECT * 
FROM #Temp -- The #Temp table does not exists in this scope!
```

To do this kind of thing using dynamic SQL you must use a global temporary table (that you must drop once done using!):

```
EXEC('SELECT * INTO ##GlobalTempFROM TableName')

SELECT * INTO #Temp
FROM ##GlobalTemp -- Since this is a global temporary table you can use it in this scope

DROP TABLE ##GlobalTemp
```